# Issue converting PostgreSQL query to DSLContext

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I am trying to convert a query I wrote and tested from the command line to a DSLContext query using jOOq and am encountering issues.  The query below  is intended to return a list of tags that match the like parameter with a wildcard from a table "campaign" with a JSONB column "tags".  This column has values formatted in the following way:

["dogs","cats","rabbits"]

```sql
select distinct A.value 
from campaign T, LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(T.tags) A 
where A.value LIKE 't%'
```

I am attempting to create this to a DSLContext in the following manner but I get an error "ERROR: argument of AND must not return a set".  Can anyone see what I can do to resolve this issue and produce the same results from my PostgreSQL query and my DSL query below?

```
final Field<String> tagField = field("jsonb_array_elements_text(tags)", String.class);

final Table<Record1<String>> lateral = 
    lateral(sql.dsl().select(a).from(CAMPAIGN)).asTable();

final Result<Record1<String>> tag = sql.dsl()
.select(tagField)
.from(CAMPAIGN, lateral)
.where(tagField.like("t"))
.fetch();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would translate to jOOQ as such:

```
Field<String> value = field(name("A", "value"), String.class);
sql.dsl()
   .selectDistinct(value)
   .from(
        CAMPAIGN, 
        lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", CAMPAIGN.TAGS)).as("A"))
   .where(value.like("t%"))
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that works.  You're a lifesaver